# Microsoft Project 2010 - Reset bar styles

Tags: ms-office, ms-project

I am using Microsoft Project to monitor my progress through a C# Project of mine.

I have different bar styles and colours, I have tried the Format -> Gantt Chart Style to set them all as one style and colour but when I attempt it only certain ones change colour and style.

Any ideas how to reset all the bars to be the same style and colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two way of change the style of a Gantt bar.

The first, as you have already tried, is to change the Gantt bar style. This will change the style of all bars in each category.

The second way is to right click on a specific bar and choose **Format Bar...**, then assign it a different color. If someone has done this, then changing the style won't have any effect on bars that have style changes applied explicitly.

To manually change a bar style, right click on the bar that isn't conforming to the style rules, and select **Format Bar...**

The following dialogue box will appear - you can click the **Reset** button at the bottom of this dialogue and the bar style will revert back to its default.

If you have a lot of bars in this state (or if some are only changed subtly), it may be worth doing the whole project programmatically, which can be done by running the following code:

```
Sub ResetGanttBarStyles()

Dim t As Task

For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If Not t Is Nothing Then
        Application.GanttBarFormatEx t.Index, Reset:=True
    End If
Next t

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This code did not change anything in 2010.

```
Sub ResetGanttBarStyles()
    Dim t As Task

    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If Not t Is Nothing Then
            Application.GanttBarFormatEx t.Index, Reset:=True
        End If
    Next t
End Sub
```

You can set all like tasks using this format, but you need to use `t.ID` not `t.index` to reference the current task.